# How to use the @RetryableTopic in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-integration-dsl

I'm wondering how to use the spring-kafka annotation `@RetryableTopic` within an integration flow.

Is there any way to apply it onto a consumer introduced by `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, directly.

However, you can invoke a spring integration flow using a Messaging Gateway from a `@KafkaListener` (that is effectively what the message driven channel adapter does).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway